# What is the scientific name of this text tokenizer method?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tokenize

I'm new to machine learning and I've seen this method on a tutorial some time ago but I cant find it anymore. I'm sure its not bag of words or one hot encoding or n-gramm tho.

example of the method:

```
This is an example sentence
```

my vocabulary will look like this:

```
This 0
is 1
an 2
example 3
sentence 4
```

so the tokenized sentence will be `0 1 2 3 4`

What is it called?

EDIT: Typo

Answer (score 1):

This is simply treating individual words (unique tokens) as **categorical features**. Categorical variables can only be assigned values from a finite set, in your case the set of non-negative integers up to *number of words*. A sentence is then represented as a sequence of tokens mapped to their value assignments. This is usually just a precursor to one-hot encoding.